# How do I put text next to a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm a student webdeveloper and need some help.
I need to copy this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Mutants_from_Space) as much as I can

I would like to put the Story and below divs in place like on the official wiki page.

The other struggle is the Gameplay "div",I just cant put the damn text next to that box correctly.

Sorry,I don't know if you need my whole long-a*s code but I put it in here,I have a jsbin link but I can't link it as I see.

```css
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #A7D7F9;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
h1 h2 {
  font-family: 'Linux Libertine', 'Georgia', 'Times', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 {
  border-bottom: 0.063em solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 0.313em;
  font-family: 'Linux Libertine', 'Georgia', 'Times', serif;
}
.contents {
  border: 0.063em solid #A2A9B1;
  width: 9.063em;
  float: left;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.info {
  border: 0.063em solid #A2A9B1;
  width: 18.125em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  direction: ltr;
  display: table;
  float: right;
  clear: all;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
}
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 95%;
}
h2 {
  border-bottom: 0.063em solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 0.313em;
}
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.edit {
  font-size: 60%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.text {
  text-align: justify;
}
.story {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.gameplay-info {
  border: 0.063em solid #A2A9B1;
  width: 188px;
  height: 198px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
}
.gameplay {
  text-align: justify;
}
.infobar {
  border: 1px solid #A2A9B1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Wiki site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/linux-libertine" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="about">
      <h1>Communist Mutants from Space</h1>
      <small>From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</small>
      <p><strong>Communist Mutants from Space </strong>is a <a href="/wiki/Fixed_shooter">fixed shooter</a> video game programmed by Stephen H. Landrum for the <a href="/wiki/Atari_2600">Atari 2600</a> with the <a href="/wiki/Starpath_Supercharger">Starpath Supercharger</a>        cassette accessory. It was published in 1982 by <a href="/wiki/Starpath">Starpath</a> (formerly Arcadia).<sup><a href="#">[2]</a></sup> The game is a variant of <a href="/wiki/Galaxian">Galaxian</a>.<sup><a href="#">[3]</a></sup>
      </p>
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Communist Mutants from Space</h3>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/85/Communist_Mutants_from_Space_cover.jpg">
        <figcaption>Cover art</figcaption>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th><a href="/wiki/Video_game_developer">Developer(s)</a>
            </th>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Starpath">Starpath</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><a href="/wiki/Video_game_programmer">Programmer(s)</a>
            </th>
            <td>Stephen H. Landrum<sup><a href="#">[1]</a></sup>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><a href="/wiki/Computing_platform">Platform(s)</a>
            </th>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Atari_2600">Atari 2600</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Release</th>
            <td><a href="/wiki/North_America">NA:</a>1982</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><a href="/wiki/Vodeo_game_genre">Genre(s)</a>
            </th>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Fixed_shooter">Fixed shooter</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Mode(s)</th>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Single-player_video_game">Single-player</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="contents">
        <h4>Contents <span class="edit">[<a href="#">hide</a>]</span></h4>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="#story">Story</a>
            <li><a href="#gameplay">Gameplay</a>
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#game-menu">Game menu</a>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#easteregg">Easter Egg</a>
              <li><a href="#references">References</a>
                <li><a href="#external-links">External Links</a>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="story">
      <h2> Story <span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h2>
      <p>Aliens from the <a href="/wiki/Communism">communist</a> planet of Rooskee are invading peaceful, democratic planets and turning their inhabitants into "Communist Mutants." The communist mutant armies are controlled by the Mother Creature, a strange
        alien who has gone mad due to irradiated <a href="/wiki/Vodka">vodka</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gameplay">
      <h2>Gameplay<span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h2> <span class="text">The player starts off with three reserve cannons. The object is to destroy the mutants aliens and, most importantly, the Mother Creature. The mutants hatch from moving eggs at the top of the screen. Because the Mother Creature replenishes eggs
      when they hatch or are destroyed, it must be defeated before the player can advance to the next wave. If a mutant or a bomb thrown by a mutant comes into contact with the cannon, the cannon will be destroyed and a reserve must be called up. A new
      cannon is awarded on every other wave.</span>
      <span class="gameplay-info">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f2/Commiemutants.png/180px-Commiemutants.png">
        The player must destroy the Mother Creature without being destroyed by the mutants and their bombs.</span>
      <h3>Game menu <span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h3>
      <p>The menu allows a variety of gameplay changes; for example, the player may toggle the shield option on or off. If activated, "shield" mode allowed a player to press down on the joystick to become invincible for a short period (only one shield was
        allotted per level). Another feature was the "time warp," which allowed the player to press up on the joystick to temporarily slow down the passage of time for his opponents (i.e., they move slower than usual). Additionally, the type of shot fired
        could be changed by activating the "penetrating fire" option (which enhanced the beam fired so that it could withstand hitting two mutants rather than a single one) and/or the "guided fire" option (which caused the beam to be moved with the joystick
        rather than firing in a straight line). The menu also allowed for multiple players (up to four) to be entered into the game. Players one and three shared the first joystick while players two and four shared the second.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="easter-egg">
      <h2> Easter Egg <span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h2>
      <p>Holding fire during power-on of the Atari 2600 causes the "HI" on the high scores screen to change to "SHL", the initials of programmer Stephen H. Landrum. <sup><a href="#">[4]</a></sup>
        <p>

    </div>
    <div class="references">
      <h2>References <span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h2>
      <ol>
        <li><b><a href="#">^</a></b> Hague James
          <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://dadgum.com/giantlist/">"The Giant List of Classic Game Programmers"</a>
        </li>
        <li><b><a href="#">^</a></b>
          <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://books.google.com.au/books?id=yy8EAAAAMBAJ&amp;lpg=PA26&amp;dq=Supercharger%20starpath&amp;pg=PA26#v=onepage&amp;q=Supercharger%20starpath&amp;f=false">I break for Arcadians:Entertainment abounds in a gaggle of games</a>,
          Page 26, InfoWorld, 27 Jun 1983,</li>
        <li><b><a href="#">^</a></b> Brundage, Darryl (June 23, 2005). <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://ataritimes.com/index.php?ArticleIDX=475">"Communist Mutants from Space"</a>. The Atari Times.</li>
        <li><b><a href="#">^</a></b> Federico, Chris. <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Server/2990/ocgs/issue8/eggstron.html">"The Complete 2600 Easter Egg Archive"</a>. Orphaned Computers & Game Systems.
          Retrieved 2007-12-28.
          <sup><a href="#">[dead link]</a></sup>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="external-links">
      <h2>External links <span class="edit">[<a href="#">edit</a>]</span></h2>
      <ul class="b">
        <li><a href="http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-2600-vcs-communist-mutants-from-space_13667.html"><i>Communnist Mutants from Space</i></a> at Atari Mania</li>
        <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AtariAge"><i>Communnist Mutants from Space</i></a> at AtariAge</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="infobar">
        <a href="#">Categories: </a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">1982 video games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Atari 2600 games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Atari 2600-only games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Cold War video games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Fixed shooters</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">North America-exclusive video games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Starpath games</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Video games developed in the United States</a>&nbsp;|
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex, it allow you to have better 'flexibility' in the layout.

Html is interpreted how it is declared. If you need an element on left, declare it before the element on right.

Better use flex than float.

https://jsfiddle.net/jfq4x07c/3/

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #A7D7F9;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
.text {
  text-align: justify;
}
.gameplay-info {
  border: 0.063em solid #A2A9B1;
  width: 188px;
  height: 198px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gameplay-container {
  display:flex;
}
.gameplay {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<span class="gameplay-container">
            <span class="gameplay-info">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f2/Commiemutants.png/180px-Commiemutants.png"> The player must destroy the Mother Creature without being destroyed by the mutants and their bombs.</span>
            <span class="text">The player starts off with three reserve cannons. The object is to destroy the mutants aliens and, most importantly,
                the Mother Creature. The mutants hatch from moving eggs at the top of the screen. Because the Mother Creature
                replenishes eggs when they hatch or are destroyed, it must be defeated before the player can advance to the
                next wave. If a mutant or a bomb thrown by a mutant comes into contact with the cannon, the cannon will be
                destroyed and a reserve must be called up. A new cannon is awarded on every other wave.</span>
            
                </span>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,looks closest to the original. Any tips for the Contents and CommunistMofS divs?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```css
#story{
  width: 80%;
}

#smallbox{
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #FFFF00;
}

#largebox{
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  height: 150px;
  background: #00FF00;
}

#smallbox, #largebox{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="story">

    <div id="smallbox">
      <p>Img + text</p>
    </div>
  
    <div id="largebox">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Update**

Please note that height and width should be set to auto, so it adjusts to the content. I only gave it a value so you could see the boxes. The important thing is that you can use float: left; to achieve what you want.